# my function in jquery not working correctly but fine in simple JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

this code is for auto-complete search

clicked topic is not showing in `search-input-box`

```js
$(function () {
  let s = ["aa", "abb", "acc", "adf"],
    search = document.querySelector(".search"),
    inputBox = document.querySelector(".search-input input"),
    suggBox = document.querySelector(".suggBox");
  inputBox.onkeyup = (e) => {
    let userData = e.target.value;
    let A = [];
    if (userData) {
      A = s.filter((d) => {
        return d.toLocaleLowerCase().startsWith(userData.toLocaleLowerCase());
      });
      A = A.map((d) => {
        return (d = `<li onclick="select(this)">${d}</li>`);
      });
      search.classList.add("active");
      show(A);
    }
  };
  function show(e) {
    suggBox.innerHTML = !e.length
      ? `<li>` + inputBox.value + `</li>`
      : e.join("");
  }
  function select(e) {
    inputBox.value = e.textContent;
  }
});
```

if i remove `$(function(){ ....})` then `select(e)` working fine

**NOTE** above code is part of some long jQuery file thats why i need solution in Jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because `select(e)` is inside anonymous function so it can be accessed, you have to create element using `document.createElement("li")` and attach the listener or simply add click listener to the document and check if target is the element that you wanted.

```
document.body.onclick = function(e) {
  if (e.target.className == 'item')
    inputBox.value = e.target.textContent
}
```

demo

```js
$(function() {
  let s = ["aa", "abb", "acc", "adf"],
    search = document.querySelector(".search"),
    inputBox = document.querySelector(".search-input input"),
    suggBox = document.querySelector(".suggBox");
  inputBox.onkeyup = (e) => {
    let userData = e.target.value;
    let A = [];
    if (userData) {
      A = s.filter((d) => {
        return d.toLocaleLowerCase().startsWith(userData.toLocaleLowerCase());
      });
      A = A.map((d) => {
        //  return (d = `<li onclick="select(this)">${d}</li>`); // replace this
        return (d = `<li class="item">${d}</li>`);
      });
      search.classList.add("active");
      show(A);
    }
  };

  function show(e) {
    suggBox.innerHTML = !e.length ?
      `<li>` + inputBox.value + `</li>` :
      e.join("");
  }

  /*function select(e) {
    inputBox.value = e.textContent;
  }*/
  $(document).on('click', '.item', function(){
    inputBox.value = this.textContent;
  })
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-input">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="search"></div>
<div class="suggBox"></div>
```